# Changing the image on a picture box on mouse click to give the user some feed back

Tags: c#, mouseevent

I am using a custom control that inherits from a picture box to simulate a button.  I have most of the functionally I want working correctly.  I want to put something in that will simulate a button press.  So that when the user presses the button something will happen to the image on the control for a split second.
Is the code below an ok solution for this or can someone suggest a better method.

Would it be using a timer that replaces the image after time x or something like that?

Thanks

```
 private void MediaButton_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Image = this.downImage;
            this.Invalidate();
            this.Refresh();

            //Do something
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);

            this.Image = this.upImage;
            this.Invalidate();
            this.Refresh();
        }
```

Update:
This is for a touch screen device

Comment: Ok, lots of suggestions to use the mouse down and mouse up.  Will test this and see how it works.  I changed the sleep value to 50, and it seems to do exactly what I want it to do, this is just to let the user know that the button has actually been pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't want to use `Thread.Sleep(xx)` here… In fact, just about any time you see code using that, you can assume it's wrong or at least a very bad idea. You also don't want a timer, because you don't want to wait a pre-determined amount of time.

Instead, let the user determine how long the "down" or "active" image is displayed. Sync it up with the `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events. Change the image to your "down" or "active" image when the `MouseDown` event is raised, and reset it back to the original image in the `MouseUp` event.

```
private void MediaButton_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{
    MediaButton.Image = downImage;
}

private void MediaButton_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{
    MediaButton.Image = upImage;
}
```

Your "down" or "active" image will be displayed as long as the user is clicking the button (has their mouse button down over the control), and then removed when they release the mouse button.

You get the kind of visual feedback you're looking for, without any of the bad design.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make the user wait by using a Sleep. This may be fun for the first few times, but it'll get old and annoying fast.

You can split the Click into MouseDown and MouseUp events. This lets the user choose how long he wants to look at each image.

Comment: Thanks for supper fast response. This isn't meant to give the user a chance to look at the image, it's meant to provide them feedback that the button has been pressed.  Do you think the user will notice if there's a sleep of 50milliseconds?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the MouseDown and MouseUp events? Then you can simulate what happens when you press a normal button. I.e. on MouseDown change the picture to something else (like depressed button) then on mouse up change it back.

Comment: That's exactly the effect I'm hoping to achieve, will test.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but seems more appropriate to split the code between mouseup and mousedown.
This will better simulate the behavior of a command button

```
private void MediaButton_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{ 
            this.Image = this.downImage; 
            this.Invalidate(); 
            this.Refresh(); 
 }

private void MediaButton_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{
            this.Image = this.upImage; 
            this.Invalidate(); 
            this.Refresh(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that you're probably not using WPF (I'm guessing WinForms), but if you use WPF you can use [Animations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx) to provide a more enriched user experience.

Comment: I'm hoping that soon we'll be using WPF, but not yet. Something to look forward to :)